# iPhone 4 app using sqlite database

Tags: ios, xcode, json, ipad, sqlite

I am making an app wherein I establish a connection with the database to store json data in sqlite3 database  by creating and inserting the data programmatically. All this works fine but I want that the next time if a user uses this app than the data should be accessed from database instead of the network. Can you suggest me a way to do so. I am establishing an asynchronous connection in ViewDidLoad method and using the json array count in number of rows in table I display the values in table by selecting the required data from the database. I want that the use should be able to view the information from database even when the connection is not established when he runs the app for the second time.

Comment: I want that the next time if a user uses this app than the data should be accessed from database instead of the network. How do I differentiate whether the user is trying to access the information for a second time and then display the information by selecting the values from the database?

Comment: Well, I would guess that you need to write the database to the phone.  And then access that DB rather than the remote one.

Comment: I have made a sqlite3 database on the terminal and have added that file to my Xcode project. I then make a table (create table if not exists..)programmatically in ViewDidLoad method and insert the values in the database in cellForRowAtIndexPath and soon after inserting the values, I select the values from database to be displayed at that particular cell. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please do guide me if the structure/way is not proper

Comment: You need to copy the database to a writable location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so.

1. When ever your application receives the data from the server, you can store a flag in NSUserDefaults and when application is launched second time, check the flag which is stored in NSUserDefault. If the flag is false download the data or else get it from database.
2. In case of no internet connection, "connection:didFailWithError" delegate will be called automatically. In "connection:didFailWithError" method check the flag once again which is stored in NSUserDefault if it is true show the data from the database or else give the "no internet connection" message.

Instead of using NSURLConnection you can also use ASIHttp library "http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/"